# How to use hooks in CS-Cart for overriding variant_item.tpl

Tags: php, smarty, cs-cart

I am new to Cs-cart, I have my new addons namely fancy color,and I am trying to use hooks in Cs-cart for overriding core functionality.

I need to override variant_item.tpl file with new content then how can I do it using hooks.

Just tell me the steps what code to write in variant_item.tpl file and where to keep new variant_item.tpl file in my fancy color addon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check also that [Fancy Color](https://www.hungryweb.net/cs-cart-addons/fancy-color-filter.html) already override **templates/addons/hw_colors/overrides/blocks/product_filters/original.tpl**

To override an entire file you need to add the new file base on this structure:

```
templates/addons/[ADDON_NAME]/overrides/[PATH]/[TPL_FILE]
```

ex: of Fancy color override

```
templates/addons/hw_colors/overrides/blocks/product_filters/original.tpl
```